# Stackoverflow, Linkedin like notification when there is new activity

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, notifications, signalr

Lots of site have notification system when there is new posts.

For example,

in [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)
[image]

in [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/)
[image]

When this is clicked the page reloads.

I wanted to implement this kind of system in my application.
So when new items are added in database, show this kind of notification, and when user clicks it. Reload the page.

Does anyone have idea of how this kind of notification works and how we can implement it?
Any post or idea regarding this would be helpful.

Also, If someone thinks this question can have more tags, feel free to add.

Comment: How do you think they work? and what happens when you try that approach?

Comment: I really don't have any idea how they work. I just wanted to know if someone has any idea and can give suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the quick idea how you can do this.

**Client side auto refresh and get content using ajax post.**

```
<h2>Notification</h2>
<div id="divNotif" style="display:none;"></div>

<script id="sessionJs" type="text/javascript">
    function GetNotification() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNotification", "Notification")',
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#divNotif").html(data);
                    $("#divNotif").fadeIn('slow');

                    setTimeout(function () { GetNotification(); }, 5000); //change timeout duration here
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    //alert("BAD:" + data.statusText);
                }
       });
    }

   GetNotification();
</script>
```

**Controller return json**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetNotification()
    {
        int notifCount = fromDb.NotificationCount;
        return Content("<span>New notification " + notifCount + "</span>", "text/html"); // returning a PartialView would be better one
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this what your idea :), one small question. Before the end of script you have called `GetNotification();` is it to call the page when it loads for first time?

Comment: @Ashwini : i have seen your code the way you fetch new notification and show in page but i guess there would be performance issue say if the GetNotification() function is fetching data from db. db will be hit again and again the way u wrote code. suppose when i million user will be on that page then just guess how many hit will be generated for database?? it would be better if you show push technique instead of polling one. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ashwini Vermas answer uses polling instead of pub/sub. It will increase trafic and put strain on the web server etc. Use SignalR instead.

I would publish all system events on a message bus then clients can subscribe to them using this library

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy

Here is a demo

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4

disclamier: I'm the author of the library

Comment: i agree with you that lots of stress will be there on db if we follow Ashwini technique. would you mind to write little code like pub sub patter to solve this situation with your library. thanks

Comment: I think its best that you look at the demo above. What kind of service bus do you have in your system. Will the messages be in process or out of process (SOA)?

Comment: I am not very advance developer. I have no idea how to design service bus. So guide me to implement it with minimum effort.

Comment: what u mean in process or out of process. I want to have bus will run in my web site .

Comment: Do you want a bus that runs in one process or that can communicate between processes

Comment: yes i need service bus will run in my asp.net web site process and i can communicate from the same project.

Comment: You can then use the same inprocess event aggregator that I use in my demo project, http://www.nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro.EventAggregator/

Comment: i can install it from Nuget but how to use it in my own project. is there any tutorial exist? guide me please. thanks

Comment: Wiki https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki demo project https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4